# Plotly Dash Visualization - Comparsion of Daily values in years

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, plotly-dash

I have prepared a Plotly Dash model to visualize monthly passenger trend over the years.
This works on groupby months,years
[image]

I have the data on daily format, yet I can't figure out how to prepare such a graph which feeds from daily data.
I have used dayofyear to solve it but now it looks ugly. And also i'm losing the data information.

```
dfFinaltest['Date'] = dfFinaltest['Date'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
dfFinaltest['dayofyear'] = dfFinaltest['Date'].dt.dayofyear
```

[image]

Is there a way to use datetime information without the year? Or any other way to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

- generate a dataframe with daily data
- generate a column for **x** that is the date re-baselined to a standard year.  (i.e. consistent across years)
- generate figure, define **xaxis** formatting

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

# generate the data
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": pd.date_range("1-jan-2018", "today")}).pipe(
    lambda d: d.assign(
        passengers=np.concatenate(
            [np.random.randint((a + 1) * 100, (a + 3) * 100, 365) for a in range(8)]
        )[0 : len(d)]
    )
)

# create columns for x and color/trace
df["x"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"].dt.strftime("%d-%b-2021"), errors="coerce")
df["year"] = df["date"].dt.year

px.line(df, x="x", y="passengers", color="year").update_layout(
    xaxis={"dtick": "M1", "tickformat": "%d-%b"}
)
```

[image]